# Snowflake rerunnable script for CICD

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to execute a script with the below steps in Snowflake:

1.) check the environment if dev, qa, sit, prod using account url, current_account function.
2.) if the current_account is qa.snowflakcomputig.com then
3.) check if there is a table named TABLEA
4.) if YES, then rename table to TABLEB

I want to achieve this using Snowflake SQL. I know we cannot write anonymous block, could this be achieved using just SQL, session variables and any new rich functions that snowflake might provide.

Comment: In what language are you using for your scripting?

Comment: I just edited the question - @Mike Walton

Comment: If you are writing it in Snowflake SQL, then why do you need to check which account you are running the SQL on?  That is the only piece of this that is confusing.  You'd need to connect to the specific account in order to execute the SQL, anyway.

Comment: when using CICD pipelines, it has to flow from dev to qa to sit to prod. There is no other way. Engineers cannot login like DBA's to execute the scripts. But there are cases when a script has to be just applied in one Environment only for multiple reasons.

Comment: But what is executing the CICD pipelines?  Your environment variables should be leveraged there, rather than in SQL after you've created your connection.  Obviously there is something in your CICD pipeline that tells you to connect to QA, right?  Use that to determine whether you should execute steps 3&4.

Comment: Until SQL SP or SQL scripting comes out in Snowflake (which should be soon), your `IF THEN` logic needs to be somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure if your requirement is truly for the code to be SQL or if it just needs to be _executed_ through SQL. This could be done with a stored procedure, but would use javascript for the logic. [SP Overview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html)

Comment: Agree with @Pepik, you need to use a stored procedure to do what you want here. It's a simple matter to run SQL statements in the JavaScript and use if blocks to determine what to run. If that works, let people know if an example would help.

Answer (score 7):

1. `SELECT current_account()` gets you this.
2. you should know which account you are connected to, so we'll skip this piece.
3. skip this, since you can accomplish the same thing by the next step.
4. `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tablename RENAME TO tablename_new` would be the easiest way to accomplish this.  If the table doesn't exist, nothing will happen.

This logic could easily be wrapped into a stored procedure, but at the moment that would have to be Javascript, not SQL.